# How to draw a linear line in graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to obtain the figure as

[image]

Could you suggest to me the way to draw it? Thanks so much.
Note that, the circle is a point (x,y).

Update: This is a simple data set for points(x,y)

```
(3,3.2)
(4,3.8)
(4,4.5)
(5,5.1)
(5.5,5.6)
(5.3,5.8)
(6.3,5.8)
(7, 7.4)
(7.3, 7.5)
(8.3, 8.5)
(9, 8.5)
(10, 11.0)
(11, 11.5)
(11.2, 11.6)
(11.5, 11.9)
(12.5, 12.9)
(13.5, 13.1)
(14, 13.8)
(15, 15.3)
(16, 16.5)
(17, 17.2)
(18, 18.4)
(19, 19.1)
```

This is my code based on suggestions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=Weight (kg), % label x axis
ylabel=Height (cm), % label y axis
axis lines=left, %set the position of the axes
xmin=0, xmax=20, % set the min and max values of the x-axis
ymin=0, ymax=20, % set the min and max values of the y-axis
clip=false
]
\addplot[only marks,mark=o] coordinates {(3,3.2) (4,3.8) (4,4.5) (5,5.1) (5.5,5.6) (5.3,5.8) (6.3,5.8) (7, 7.4) (7.3, 7.5) (8.3, 8.5) (9, 8.5) (10, 11.0) (11, 11.5) (11.2, 11.6) (11.5, 11.9) (12.5, 12.9) (13.5, 13.1) (14, 13.8) (15, 15.3) (16, 16.5) (17, 17.2) (18, 18.4) (19, 19.1)};
\addplot [only marks] table {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @percusse: I have updated dataset

Comment: Thanks percusse. I have read your post but it is different. In my case, I draw the circle points from dataset and the line is `y=x`

Comment: `\addplot [samples at={0,20}] {x};`

Comment: ... and to get the circles you could do `\addplot[only marks,mark=o] coordinates {(3,3.2) (4,3.8) (4,4.5) (5,5.1) (5.5,5.6) (5.3,5.8) (6.3,5.8) (7, 7.4) (7.3, 7.5) (8.3, 8.5) (9, 8.5) (10, 11.0) (11, 11.5) (11.2, 11.6) (11.5, 11.9) (12.5, 12.9) (13.5, 13.1) (14, 13.8) (15, 15.3) (16, 16.5) (17, 17.2) (18, 18.4) (19, 19.1)};`...

Comment: Great. So. where is the line `y=x`? Thanks

Comment: My previous comment should give you y=x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\addplot [samples at={0,20}] {x};` gives you a black line for y=x from x=0 to x=20.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=Weight (kg), % label x axis
ylabel=Height (cm), % label y axis
axis lines=left, %set the position of the axes
xmin=0, xmax=20, % set the min and max values of the x-axis
ymin=0, ymax=20, % set the min and max values of the y-axis
]
\addplot[only marks,mark=o] coordinates {(3,3.2) (4,3.8) (4,4.5) (5,5.1) (5.5,5.6) (5.3,5.8) (6.3,5.8) (7, 7.4) (7.3, 7.5) (8.3, 8.5) (9, 8.5) (10, 11.0) (11, 11.5) (11.2, 11.6) (11.5, 11.9) (12.5, 12.9) (13.5, 13.1) (14, 13.8) (15, 15.3) (16, 16.5) (17, 17.2) (18, 18.4) (19, 19.1)};
\addplot [samples at={0,20}] {x};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```